# Managed browser in Lotus Notes 8.5.3 is IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer, lotus-notes, composite-component, xulrunner

I am using the managed browser in Lotus Notes in a composite application.
Even though I have IE 9 installed on my machine it looks like the default webbrowser used by the managed browser is

Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C)

is there a way to change this to a more modern browser or to the XULRunner?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No it is the IE9 in compatibility mode:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/23/introducing-ie9-s-user-agent-string.aspx

The difference is the Trident-String (Trident 5.0 means IE9).

You may want so set the X-UA-COMPATIBLE Flag inside your Web-Site.